# Google apps script rendering a chart through an UI, how to display the chart

Tags: google-api, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have created a UI web app in google apps script which access a database in a spreadsheet, manipulates the data and then puts it into a chart. Now my problem is that I get get the chart to be displayed back into the Ui. I don't even know if that is a possibility, but something along those lines. This is what i have tried thus far:

- First I created a chart in the doGet function and then tried to
  access and edit after i took in some info from the user. The problem
  was that when i .build() the chart it become a generic object and
  cannot be edited.

  Second I tried to .add the chart to the Ui after
  taking in info, but i could not get the ui to update. again i don't
  know the right way to do this.

Let me know if you need any additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great recent blog post from Google on coding up [dashboards in Apps Script](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/introducing-dashboards-in-google-apps.html) complete with a new [charts dashboard tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/charts_dashboard) on the developer site. It strikes me that it may be suitable for you as it lets you prepare the data but then you can allow the user to interact with the UI via the chart controls and you don't have to wire up so much in "native" uiApp yourself.

Let us know how you go.

Comment: I may be able to work with it. I have not looked, but do you know if there is a way to change the data of the dashboard after taking in some UI info? It is not ideal, but worst comes to worst I can make do. Do you have a suggestion if I want to continue heading in the direction i am going now?

Comment: Sorry, with uiApp, I don't know enough to say it's possible with say clientHandlers or not. With HtmlService it may and with controls available on the chart objects (a la dashboard example) it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recreate your chart completely, i.e. every time your spreadsheet is changed (for instance new row is inserted), you have to take data from it, build a new chart, delete old one and place the new chart instead of the deleted one.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i was unclear. I want to chart to appear in the Ui not in a spreadsheet, so that multiple users can use the app at once

Comment: @Rommel. I understood. I have a Web App with similar functionality as yours. It takes data from a spreadsheet and produces multiple charts using the data. When user changes some parameters, for instance, period in X-Axis, the application takes data from the cache or rereads them from the spreadsheet and recreates the charts.

Comment: I got it working, what I was going wrong was that I forgot a return app in one of the functions so the when i returned the app it never had the new charts on it.